# How to create a class to wrap GLUT?

Tags: c++, glut

I'm writing a game for school in OpenGL. Since there will be several more similar assignments I want to make a small framework for doing common things in OpenGL. I have made a few simple games before and I usually break it down into an IO class to handle input and drawing to the screen, Game class for the main game loop/logic, and classes for whatever objects there are in the game.

Before I was using SDL, so my question is, is this the right way of going about this in OpenGL? I've already ran into some trouble. I want my IO class to handle initializing the window, drawing the scene, and mouse clicks. So the constructor looked like this:

```
IO::IO()
{
    currWindowSize[0] = DEF_WIDTH;
    currWindowSize[1] = DEF_HEIGHT;

    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA );
    glutInitWindowPosition( INIT_WINDOW_POSITION[0], INIT_WINDOW_POSITION[1] );
    glutInitWindowSize( currWindowSize[0], currWindowSize[1] );
    glutCreateWindow( "TEST" );

    setUp();

    glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

However, `drawScene` is a class method. Is there a way to pass a class method to `glutDisplayFunc()` without making it static?

Comment: That's a lot of code to put in a constructor. I'd keep your ctor light and have explicit setup and teardown functions. Also, what advantage does wrapping the OpenGL calls into C++ classes actually give you? What are you trying to achieve

Comment: @zebrabox: No, that is the constructors and destructors job. Explicit setup and teardown functions just violate class invariants and allow you to create a whole new class of errors. If the constructor is too big, it's probably a sign that your class needs to be split up into multiple smaller ones, *not* that you should rename your constructor to "setup()". In this case, the OP wants *one* class to handle "rendering", "interfacing with OpenGL", "taking input from mouse" and "keeping track of the scene". Which is about 15 times as many responsibilities as a single class should have.

Comment: Its not exactly what you want, but you might find the structure of this simple framework useful: http://gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Tutorial_Framework:Base

Comment: Thanks for the input. @jalf: I guess this is just something I need to work on then. My logic was that if I wrap the OpenGL calls into a separate C++ class that it would make it easier for future programs.

Comment: @jalf. The constructor is called as part of the class instance creation i.e it is implicit not explicit. Putting heaps of code in the ctor/dtor is just hiding a potential spike on object creation/destruction IMO and makes tracking down issues harder. In my line of work I need to know exactly what's using CPU and memory and when, so personally I prefer long setup/teardown to be explicit but then maybe I'm just outdated :)

Comment: @zebrabox: That makes no sense. If you need to know where CPU time is being spent, you use a profiler (or just stop the debugger at random times). And those approaches have *no* problem seeing when time is being spent in a constructor. Moreover, I tend to rate correctness over performance: It should never be possible to bring an instance in an invalid or inconsistent state - which means that the constructor must do what it takes to bring the instance into the expected state. Relying on the user to *remember* to call extra functions before the object can be used is needlessly error-prone

Comment: @jalf : 'Moreover, I tend to rate correctness over performance'. Nice if you have the luxury to do so :) I think if you're using RAII then your argument is a good one because the RAII approach means that the ctor/ dtor dictate the whole object lifetime. As to a profiler - of course but when you have 500,000 files things become a lot more complicated. I'm not very modern in my C++ ( you've probably noticed that before ) so I tend to use it in a very C like way - not wrong IMO but perhaps old-fashioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the `glutDisplayFunc()` doesn't take a `void*` pointer so you could've fake an object context. You will have to make a static function that can call into the correct IO instance using a static variable.

I see some slight trouble with your pattern also, though. As far as I know, `glutMainLoop()` never returns until you terminate the GLUT context, therefore you have a constructor that practically never returns, so your program flow is unreasonable. You should move that call into a separate `run()` method in your class.

(Personally I would use GLFW, which avoids the entire callback mess with GLUT, although you have to write your mainloop.)

Comment: Yep ctor as coded is effectively a setup and main function combined. So I agree on the 'run' suggestion but I'd also put an explicit 'setup' ( and corresponding 'shutdown') function

Comment: Whoops, I didn't see that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Two points,

First, glutMainLoop never returns, and starts dispatching messages. Because you called it from your constructor your class is potentially not properly constructed yet. Additionally glut does support more than one window, and glutModalLoop only needs to be called once.

Second, as you have noted, the method passed to glutDisplayFunc must be static. You will need a static array associating glut window id's with IO pointers. When glutCreateWindow is called by an IO instance, store the returned id and IO instance in the array. Whenever the static drawScene is called you would call glutGetWindow to get the id of the current window, and look  up the associated IO pointer and call the non static drawScene implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> Before I was using SDL, so my question
>   is, is this the right way of going
>   about this in OpenGL?

I'd rather bypass GLUT completely (if you want to learn the inner guts of OpenGL and your OS windowing system interface). Plus GLUT is not supported on the iPhone (if you want to target this platform in the future).

So the idea would be to use `WGL` on Windows, `GLX` on Linux and `CGL` on OS X.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This is for a class so I'm stuck using GLUT.

Comment: I doubt iPhone is the target anyway. I believe using an interface that is pretty much platform agnostic, like GLUT and GLFW, is better to use than any platform-specific FXs like the ones you mention (if I stand correct). Last autumns programming project recommended GLUT, however I chose GLFW and easily dodged some trouble that kept haunting everyone else using GLUT (erratic rendering behaviour).