# Pass pointer to class function to GLUT

Tags: c++, function-pointers, glut

I have a class

```
class App {
private:
    float angle;

public:
    App();
    int OnExecute();
    void OnLoop();
    void OnRender();
    bool OnInit();
    void OnCleanup();
};

//In my cpp file:
int App::OnExecute() {
    if (OnInit() == false) {
        return -1;
    }

    OnLoop();
    OnRender();

    OnCleanup();

    return 0;
}

bool App::OnInit() {
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA );
    glutInitWindowPosition(-1,-1);
    glutInitWindowSize(1024,768);
    glutCreateWindow("D&D VT");

    glutDisplayFunc(Render); //Why can't I put this->OnRender
    //glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);
    //glutIdleFunc(Render);

    return true;
}
```

I commented the line where I'm struggling with doing what I am trying to do. I want to pass a pointer to my class function. I've tried about 4 different ways to do this and I get compile errors everyway unless I create a non-class function to pass.

I've tried passing `this->*OnRender`.
I tried declaring the function as a `virtual void` and as `void (App::*OnRender)()`.  I tried defining it as `void &App::OnRender() {};`.

Each time a different error complaining about my syntax combinations. I'm missing something.

Comment: Try making `OnRender` static. It probably doesn't take `thiscall`.

Comment: exactly the error message, I should have added that.  I'll try it.  Thanks for fixing the code format.  I was doing it but then told me you did it for me.  It looked right when I added it. :)

Comment: Yep.  Static works.  Makes sense, if I remember right, static in a class deceleration means there is one shared member for all instances of the same class.  thiscall meant it was passing the specific class OnRender but by making it static, there is no 'thiscall' version because all calls go to the same function.  At least that's how I understand it.  Either way, thanks mwerschy.  Works fantastic.

Comment: Yup pretty much correct :) `thiscall` will implicitly require another parameter pointing to `this`. And `glutDisplayFunc` cant provide that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a class to wrap OpenGL drawing for a game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129388/how-to-create-a-class-to-wrap-opengl-drawing-for-a-game)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> glutDisplayFunc(Render); //Why can't I put this->OnRender
> ```

Becuase and C and C++ don't work that way. What you're thinking of are so called closures. `this->Render` is syntactic sugar combining two distinct elements:

- A pointer to a certain instance of a class

and

- a pointer to a class member

Both must be combined in a particular way to be dereferenceable. In C++ you could write a callback function taking two parameters (pointer to class instance `this` and pointer to class member `&App::Render`) but *GLUT* which is the framework you're using is written in C and its API is C. And C doesn't know classes and it doesn't know class members, so what you try to do is next to impossible to implement without doing crazy things, like using *ffcall* to create closures in-situ.

My recommendation: Don't use GLUT. GLUT is just *some* framework, which you can replace anytime. How about using Qt? It got proper OpenGL support and is much nicer to work with, if you want to do everything C++ OOP.

Comment: Because until yesterday I didn't know the difference between glut and openGL, and SDL.   I don't even know what Qt is :p  I will check it out.  My only experience in school is 2 semesters of C++, 1 Semester of mixed C and Assembly but only to really teach computer architecture.  We only ran console apps, so I know very little in terms of GUI.  I went through all of SDL Tutorials and then got to the openGL portion.  Then decided I wanted to use openGL and found glut.  I am at least starting to understand how everything is related if not getting closer to my project goal.

Comment: Well after looking more into it, qt could work, but SDL with openGL seems to be easier for me to work with.  I'll skip over glut because I read SDL provides more access to openGL than glut does.

However, what I was trying to do wasn't impossible and I didn't have to do anything crazy.  I just had to declare my class function as static to send the address of the function to glut.  Although, not important now.

Answer (score 0):

The key to solving this dilemma lies in these 3 `GLUT` functions.

```
int glutCreateWindow(char *name);
void glutSetWindow(int win);
int glutGetWindow(void);
```

Without a window, you can't display anything and you can query for a window. Hence, you need to associate this window `int` with a pointer to anything you want: a pointer to an instance, or some struct, whatever you like. Example:

```
static ::std::unordered_map<int, Window*> windows;

extern "C" void display_callback()
{
  auto const window_id(glutGetWindow());

  windows[window_id]->do_something();
}
```

If you are using `freeglut`, then take a look at these functions:

```
glutGetWindowData()
glutSetWindowData().
```

Comment: You're making the assumption that there's a strict 1:1 relationship between windows and display callback handlers. Depending on the structure of the program this however may not be the case. It's a common programming pattern with GLUT to alter the display callback function depending on the state of the program.

Comment: I am assuming a 1:1 relationship between a window and an instance of a class that is governing the window. The display function queries what window it is running under and from this it deduces the pointer to an instance. Even if you alter the display function, it can still do the query.